# error on bundle install for sassc on cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cygwin, bundler

I am using Cygwin to on my windows machine to use RVM and run my rails project. Now when I run bundle install it is showing the following message.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/Shila/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sassc-2.2.1/ext
/home/Shila/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby.exe -I /home/Shila/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200414-4993-go8jx2.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/Shila/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sassc-2.2.1/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/Shila/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sassc-2.2.1/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling ./libsass/src/ast.cpp
CC: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1plus’: spawn: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:236: ast.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/Shila/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sassc-2.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/Shila/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/extensions/x86_64-cygwin/2.6.0/sassc-2.2.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sassc (2.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sassc -v '2.2.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sass-rails was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
    sassc-rails was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
      sassc
```

ruby version is  2.6.3

Bundler version 1.17.3

Comment: have you installed the cygwin `gems` package ? https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/rubygems.html

Comment: yes, that one is installed.

Comment: do you have gcc insstalled. Try compiling and running the classic hello.c and hello.cpp tests.

Comment: @DougHenderson gcc is installed. I will compile and run hello.c and cpp..

Comment: @DougHenderson thanks. your comments give me idea I had to add g++ and libgccpp1. I guess it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add new gcc-g++ and libgccpp1

[image]